# Erlang data types

Tags: string, erlang

What is the benefit of having string as a list of integers rather than an independent data type in Erlang? Is this to make the string manipulation easier and more efficient? Are there any other reasons for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe (TM) that the only benefit was to allow them to implement wide character representations (unicode, utf-x, ...) in a robust way. On the down side, the performance is much less efficient than linear byte arrays. That said, Erlang was never really meant to be used for heavy string manipulations and so the performance of doing so shouldn't matter.

Comment: Wrong, performance is better with strings as lists, at least when working with the strings. Lists are VERY nice to work with. There was a discussion on the mailing list earlier where one guy measured and found strings as lists was faster, to his surprise. He shouldn't have been surprised. Granted though that they take more space.

Comment: Hi @rvirding, thanks for the input but could you please explain what you mean by "at least when working with strings"? I must be missing something. As a sequential memory buffer, all access is O(1) but a list is by definition O(n). For example, if i want to determine the fourth character of the string, I know the beginning address of the string and the size of a character so I can immediately determine the value of the 4th char by checking the value at BASE_ADDR + (4 * size(CHAR)).

Comment: (too long) With a list I would need to jump from one character to the next following the pointer references 4 consecutive times. This is of course random access, insertion or 'appending' are different stories.

Comment: I would say most of the time you are working with a string you are not just looking at various characters in the string but actually modifying them. This slow with binaries as most operations end up copying the binary. More important: direct character access is impossible to do with unicode! Seeing the unicode code points must be encoded, usually with UTF-8, they will be of different sizes and you must traverse the binary stepping over the code points until you get to the one you want. This is faster with a list. And with a list you don't need an encoding.